# how to place listview and toolstrip into a static variable

Tags: c#

Hey everyone I am not sure if anyone can help me on this issue or not. Let me explain the setup
First I have a main form and a add form and a class file that has the save code in it,in the save code I have to enable the listview and enable a toolstrip button.

The add form is used to insert data into a listview that's on the main form

Now I was told that I could do something like

`public statuc Listview LV1;`  in the main form then 
on the add form I could do LV1.whatever .

This is so I don't have to do a method with 2 arguments.

The goes is I need to be able to access the listview or what ever I need that's ont eh main form from the class file but through the add form since the save button on the add form would call the method in the class file.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have:

1. Main form (MF) with ListView (LV) and ToolStrip with button.
2. Add form (AF) with UI elements such as labels and text boxes that you are using to present values of some class. There also should be OK and Cancel buttons for accepting or rejecting user input.
3. Class (CL) with several properties that user needs to fill-in. This class has Save method that captures values from AF. When users exits with OK you want to store instance of CL into LV of MF.

If this is what you have in mind I would suggest to do following:

1. Create Add method in MF with parameter ListView LV.
2. In this method you need to instantiate AF and save LV in some variable of AF.
3. Show AF form.
4. In btn_OK method instantiate CL and fill-in properties based on user entered values and add instance to LV variable or
5. In btn_OK instantiate CL and invoke Save method that will have AF as parameter. In Save method pick-up values of AF fields and put them in CL properties. Add *this* in LV using AF variable for LV.

Static variables are not used here since, in this scenario, you do not need static variables. However, you may create static variable for LV (MyListView for example) and set it's value to LV instance (MyListView = ListView1 for example). After that you can access it through MainForm.MyListView in AF and CL as needed.